# Missing switch on Beseler 45MCRX

Tags: film, developing

I received a Beseler 45MCRX enlarger.  I don't have a timer or a switch for it, so I don't have a way to operate it, other than connecting the lamp directly to power.

Judging by [this manual](http://www.jollinger.com/photo/cam-coll/manuals/enlargers/beseler/Beseler_45M.pdf), it looks like the switch is merely shorting the two pins of the switch socket.  I'm afraid to wire something to do that myself as the socket looks like a regular two prong 110 volt socket.  Usually shorting hot to neutral is a bad thing.

Is it safe to short those two pins together?

Comment: You can use switch like this: https://www.amazon.com/HBN-Wireless-Weatherproof-Grounded-Included/dp/B07WX2NBWR/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=power+switch+for+enlarger&qid=1639580417&sr=8-3

Comment: As I recall, there was never a consideration to manually switch it, it was always plugged into a timer, like a GraLab. Google GraLab to see what they look like. http://www.gralab.com/products/details.asp?ID=11

Comment: @cmason, I think if you look at item 14A in the manual and the section on Timers, you'll see that it was intended to be manually switched.

Comment: I meant to ask, and it isn't clear from the diagrams but where does the power come in from the wall?

Comment: @BobT, it's not shown in the manual.  There's a power cable coming out of the box with 22 and 14A.  If I remember correctly, the cable comes out of the back of the box, but I don't have the enlarger with me right now.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what "the two pins of the switch socket" refers to in your question. If it's 14A in the diagram, then I don't see any other way to operate the switch other than shorted/notshorted.

You might try plugging 14D (lamp cord) into a separate switched extension cord and switching the lamp directly (bypassing the Resistrol if it exists in your setup). There are inexpensive switch/dimmer cords that can perform the same function as the Resistrol if so desired.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain that well.  Yes, the switch socket is 14A.  I agree, it sure looks like it needs to be shorted.  That just seems scary to me.  I plugged the lamp directly into 14A and it did not light up.  The enlarger came with a Resistrol, but I think the Resistrol doesn't get power unless 14A is shorted, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Electric cord set 14A is an ordinary 110V AC plug. You can test by plugging and un-plugging this cord set. This should, if the lamp is good, allow you to light the lamp. Knowing this is factual, you can procure a switched plug or a timer that will turn off and on appliances.

Initially, this enlarger was used with a large wire-wound adjustable resistor that allowed the operator to dim the lamp. You can use a modern dimmer switch as a substitute.

Comment: the lamp does not light when I plug it into 14A.  I'm thinking BobT is right. The enlarger did come with the resistor you mentioned: the Resistrol.

Comment: Check the bulb for continuity with a volt meter. Check the voltage specification of suppled lamp. Now procure a bulb that will fit the socket, even if it is the wrong size. Substitute this bulb and see if it lights. I think your bulb is likely bad.

Comment: The lamp does light when plugged directly into power.